# Using sqoop in Cloudera Quickstart VM to import data from host machine

Tags: mysql, hadoop, virtual-machine, cloudera, sqoop

I have installed the Cloudera Quickstart VM on my windows 8 host machine. I would like to know if it is possible to use sqoop in the VM to import data from a mysql database running in the **host machine.** The VM runs centOS. If so, what would be the configuration changes that i'd have to make.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you have your VM setup.  If your VM is just using an internal network for your network interface devices, then no.

If your network interface devices are setup to use NAT or bridged, then yes.  Bridged network interfaces are the easiest to work with, as it involves no routing.  If your network is set to bridged mode, then your VM will be getting a DCHP address from the same location as your Host.  Connecting to the mysql database is just the usual `<hostip>:3306`.

If the network device is set to NAT, then you've got to figure out how to route between the two networks.  It's probably just a lot easier to set your VM to bridged mode than cover how to route your NAT'd interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you are able to ping your local machine from VM. Try ping  in vm. If it works then sqoop should be able to connect to your local mysql. I am using same configuration as you are  using and it works fine for me.